# Formatting ticks labels matplotlib and adding string value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to format my xtick and ytick values to two decimal places in float and also add a "%" at the end.  How would I go about that?

```
x_sum = cm.sum(axis=0)*100
y_sum = cm.sum(axis=1)*100
plt.xticks(tick_marks, x_sum)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, y_sum)
```

Currently, the ticks give me long decimal values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seen from the question, you want to set the ticks manually anyways, so you just need to format the ticklabels,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cm = np.sort(np.random.rand(64)).reshape((8,8))
tick_marks=np.arange(8)

plt.imshow(cm)

x_sum = cm.sum(axis=0)*100
y_sum = cm.sum(axis=1)*100

fmt = lambda x: "{:.2f}%".format(x)

plt.xticks(tick_marks, [fmt(i) for i in x_sum], rotation=90)
plt.yticks(tick_marks, [fmt(i) for i in y_sum])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

For automatic percentage labeling, the `matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter` makes sense:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

cm = np.sort(np.random.rand(64)).reshape((8,8))

plt.imshow(cm, extent=(0,80,0,80))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(decimals=2))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(decimals=2))

plt.gca().tick_params(axis="x",rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A clean way to define the formatting of tick labels is to create your own tick formatter. This is possible by utilizing matplotlib's [FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter).

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def format_tick_labels(x, pos):
    return '{0:.2f}%'.format(x)

values = range(20)
f, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(format_tick_labels))
ax.plot(values)
```

[image]